# how take all posts published by a user on facebook with python

Tags: python, facebook

I'm trying to write a code which takes all my posts from facebook and prints them. Helping me with the web, I wrote this code:

```
import facebook
import json
import requests

access_token = "xxx"

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
profile = graph.get_object("me")
posts = graph.get_connections(profile["id"], "posts")

while True:
    try:
        for post in posts["data"]:
            print str(post['created_time'])
        posts = requests.get(posts["paging"]["next"]).json()
    except KeyError:
        break
```

It works great but I’m having trouble printing any post published from 2009 to 2013, it let me print just post from 2014 til now. Also my goal is to be able to print just a specific number of posts (be able to choose the amount of post that I want to print, for example print 1 or 10 or even 1000 posts), but I can’t find a way to do that. I have tried to modify the code in this way but it still doesn’t working:

```
import facebook
import json
import requests

access_token = "xxx"

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
profile = graph.get_object("me")
posts = graph.get_object(id='/me', fields='posts.limit(' + postsNum + '){created_time,message,application}')

while True:
    try:
        for post in posts["posts"]["data"]:
            print str(post['created_time'])
        posts = requests.get(posts["posts"]["data"]["paging"]["next"]).json()
    except KeyError:
        break
```

Comment: I don't know about older posts but for the number of posts you can add a counter in your loop and an if statement to end it.

Comment: The Graph API isn’t good when it comes to “historical” data from way back, experience shows that you have to expect “holes” in what data you can actually get back. The `limit` parameter would be the right way to limit the number of results - but you can not just go as high as you want with that, the maximum limit of data you can get with one request is limited to 100, for some endpoints even just 25, IIRC. You will have to use pagination afterwards, to get more data.

Comment: @KostasCharitidis i have already tried to do that but also in this way, I’m unable to print my old post. Furthermore if I add a if statement with a break instruction inside it, the program stop working

Comment: Then maybe something like this `for post in posts["data"][:10]:`

Comment: @misorude Thank you for your help. I thought I have done it with the try/except. I know that the limit, allows to limit the number of posts for any page that API graph gives me back. If the value hasn’t been specified, any page gives back 25 post maximum, but for this matter i think that I did it that way. In the first part of the code, is not specified any limitation but I’m able to print all the post until 2014

Answer (score 0):

As for all posts, especially the historical ones, then it is good to make a dump of data.

You can download data on https://www.facebook.com/dyi/

Screenshot of request only for posts:
[image: Select post for dump]